# DNS: Unable to find specific GPG server

Tags: linux, dns, gnupg, pacman

I would like to upgrade my system on Arch Linux distro by

```
yay -Syu
```

but unfortunately, when I try to import new GPG key, I've got DNS error

```
    :: PGP keys need importing:
 -> 8FD3D9A8D3800305A9FFF259D1742AD60D811D58, required by: spotify
==> Import? [Y/n] y
:: Importing keys with gpg...
dirmngr[1062283.5]: handler for fd 5 started
dirmngr[1062283.5]: DBG: chan_5 -> # Home: /home/pilec/.gnupg
dirmngr[1062283.5]: DBG: chan_5 -> # Config: [none]
dirmngr[1062283.5]: DBG: chan_5 -> OK Dirmngr 2.2.23 at your service
dirmngr[1062283.5]: connection from process 1067439 (1000:1000)
dirmngr[1062283.5]: DBG: chan_5 <- GETINFO version
dirmngr[1062283.5]: DBG: chan_5 -> D 2.2.23
dirmngr[1062283.5]: DBG: chan_5 -> OK
dirmngr[1062283.5]: DBG: chan_5 <- KS_GET -- 0x8FD3D9A8D3800305A9FFF259D1742AD60D811D58
dirmngr[1062283.5]: DBG: get_dns_cname(hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net): No name
dirmngr[1062283.5]: DBG: dns: resolve_dns_name(hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net): No name
dirmngr[1062283.5]: resolving 'hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net' failed: No name
dirmngr[1062283.5]: DBG: Using TLS library: GNUTLS 3.6.15
dirmngr[1062283.5]: DBG: http.c:connect_server: trying name='hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net' port=443
dirmngr[1062283.5]: DBG: get_dns_cname(hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net): No name
dirmngr[1062283.5]: DBG: dns: resolve_dns_name(hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net): No name
dirmngr[1062283.5]: resolving 'hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net' failed: No name
dirmngr[1062283.5]: can't connect to 'hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net': host not found
dirmngr[1062283.5]: error connecting to 'https://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net:443': No name
dirmngr[1062283.5]: command 'KS_GET' failed: No name
dirmngr[1062283.5]: DBG: chan_5 -> ERR 167772380 No name <Dirmngr>
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
dirmngr[1062283.5]: DBG: chan_5 <- BYE
dirmngr[1062283.5]: DBG: chan_5 -> OK closing connection
dirmngr[1062283.5]: handler for fd 5 terminated
```

But, I'm able to get proper DNS response from dig:

```
dig hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net                                             

; <<>> DiG 9.16.8 <<>> hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 10985
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net.  IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net. 3555 IN   A       209.244.105.201

;; Query time: 20 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Wed Nov 25 23:58:01 CET 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 73
```

Additional info:

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf

search home
nameserver 8.8.8.8


# cat /etc/nsswitch.conf 
# Name Service Switch configuration file.
# See nsswitch.conf(5) for details.

passwd: files systemd
group: files systemd
shadow: files

publickey: files

hosts: files mymachines myhostname resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns
networks: files

protocols: files
services: files
ethers: files
rpc: files

netgroup: files
```

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I found a solution,

there was a problem with spotify package and it's solveable by pinned comment in discussion under spotify package - https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/spotify/#pinned-747857

So I ran

```
curl -sS https://download.spotify.com/debian/pubkey_0D811D58.gpg | gpg --import -
```

and everythings works fine now!